# Отключение конкретной сессии / всех сессий

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Добрый день!
Есть темповая таблица, которую необходимо альтернуть (добавить столбец).
Понятное дело, при 300 активных сессиях кто-то эту таблицу использует - из за этого валится ora-14450.

Могу я как то отследить, какая именно сессия обращается к необходимой мне таблице? 
И
 `alter system kill ...`?

Если же это отследить невозможно - как отключить все активные сессии?

Comment: заблокировать таблицу нельзя что ли?

Comment: Понадобилось именно сейчас - когда уже имеются сессии

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27111572/1216425

Comment: `ALTER SYSTEM KILL/DISCONNECT SESSION`. Увы, вышибаемые сессии нужно указывать поштучно.

Comment: @teran - благодарю - то, что было необходимо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получить информацию о сессиях, использующих временную таблицу можно следующим запросом:

```
select s.*
  from v$lock l, dba_objects d, v$session s
 where d.owner='СХЕМА' and d.OBJECT_NAME='ИМЯ-ТАБЛИЦЫ'
   and l.id1=d.object_id and l.type='TO' and s.sid=l.sid
```

далее сессии можно убить с помощью `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#`, где sid и serial# взяты из предыдущего запроса. Если сессий много, можно убить их все автоматически, следующим PL/SQL блоком (предварительно проверив то ли вы получаете, что надо, первым запросом):

```
begin
for c1 in(select distinct s.sid, s.serial#
            from v$lock l, dba_objects d, v$session s
           where d.owner='СХЕМА' and d.OBJECT_NAME='ИМЯ-ТАБЛИЦЫ'
             and l.id1=d.object_id and l.type='TO' and s.sid=l.sid) loop
   execute immediate 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||c1.sid||','||c1.serial#||'''';
end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

В таких случаях часто бывает достаточным просто установить [`DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams068.htm#REFRN10267) перед выполнением DDL:

```
alter session set ddl_lock_timeout=600;
```

Если в течении 10 минут (600 секунд) объект освободится даже на очень короткий промежуток времени, то Oracle сможет выполнить DDL

Comment: Тоже так обычно делаю. Но кто-то мне сказал, что так делать не рекомендуется (почему правда не помню), не зря же по-умолчанию этот параметер 0.

Comment: @0xdb, мне тоже было бы интересно узнать почему не рекомендуется...

Comment: Честно не помню, пытался в процесс, который таблицы меняет, прописать. В угол поставили, сладкого лишили.

Comment: @0xdb, мне кажется значение `0` по умолчанию - для совместимости со старыми (< 11.1) весриями. Я попытался по-быстрому найти потенциальные проблемы с `ddl_lock_timeout` и ничего "военного" не нашёл. Надо бы еще на MOS посмотреть...

Comment: Хорошо, если найдёте, добавте в ответ.